# React auto recompile WebStorm

Tags: webpack, webstorm, babeljs

I'm using WebStorm for react.js app development. I created starting project with `create-react-app`. <kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd> would work very well to refresh changes and recompile but in WebStorm saving is automatic and it does not always kick in.

I tried setting File Watcher with Babel but it has some issues with arrow functions. ES2015 should allow them.

[image]

[image]

After that I tried webpack and then things went sideways so much that I had to purge everything and clone my repo and set dependencies again...
First problem were arrow functions, then CSS, then images, then ... js was blocked because of incompatible MIME something...

webpack.conf.js:

```js
var config = {
 entry: './main.js',

 output: {
  path:'/',
  filename: 'public/index.js',
 },

 devServer: {
  inline: true,
  port: 8080
 },

 module: {
  loaders: [
   {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',

    query: {
     plugins: ['transform-runtime','transform-class-properties'],
     presets: ['es2015', 'react']
    }
   },{ test: /\.svg$/, loaders: ['babel?presets[]=react', 'svg-jsx'] }
  ]
 }
}

module.exports = config;
```

package.json

```js
var config = {
 entry: './main.js',

 output: {
  path:'/',
  filename: 'public/index.js',
 },

 devServer: {
  inline: true,
  port: 8080
 },

 module: {
  loaders: [
   {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',

    query: {
     plugins: ['transform-runtime','transform-class-properties'],
     presets: ['es2015', 'react']
    }
   },{ test: /\.svg$/, loaders: ['babel?presets[]=react', 'svg-jsx'] }
  ]
 }
}

module.exports = config;
```

I don't know which files to include so ask in comments and I add them.

WHAT DO I WANT?
I want auto refresh/recompile when I change something in files. Just like <kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd> feature promises. And I want that in WebStorm. That file watcher looks easier to fix.

EDIT1:
I tried disabling `safe write` (same webpack conf, error listing follows):

```js
ERROR in ./src/index.css
Module parse failed: D:\WebstormProjects\reactive-poet\src\index.css Unexpected token (1:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| body {
|   margin: 0;
|   padding: 0;
 @ ./src/index.js 19:0-22
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./src/App.css
Module parse failed: D:\WebstormProjects\reactive-poet\src\App.css Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| :root{
|  --app-width: 600px;
|  --app-height: 600px;
 @ ./src/App.js 37:0-20
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css
Module parse failed: D:\WebstormProjects\reactive-poet\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap-theme.css Unexpected token (6:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
|  */
| .btn-default,
| .btn-primary,
| .btn-success,
 @ ./src/index.js 5:0-49
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module parse failed: D:\WebstormProjects\reactive-poet\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css Unexpected token (7:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  */
| /*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */
| html {
|   font-family: sans-serif;
|   -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 @ ./src/index.js 3:0-43
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./src/App.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'svg-jsx' in 'D:\WebstormProjects\reactive-poet'
 @ ./src/App.js 53:12-41
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./src/tools/transitions/animations.css
Module parse failed: D:\WebstormProjects\reactive-poet\src\tools\transitions\animations.css Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| .react-transitions-top {
|  z-index: 99 !important;
| }
 @ ./src/App.js 35:0-45
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/index.js
webpack: Failed to compile
```

Comment: Have you disabled `safe write` as recommended by the official webpack docs in [Adjusting Your Text Editor](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#adjusting-your-text-editor)?

Comment: I just did and it didn't help. `ERROR in ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css
Module parse failed: D:\WebstormProjects\reactive-poet\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap-theme.css Unexpected token (6:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.` and arrow functions again

Comment: The error has nothing to do with watch mode, it's just that you didn't configure webpack to handle CSS. The suggested change was to fix: "*webstorm saving is automatic and it does not always kick in*". So try it again with `create-react-app`.

Comment: Thank you, that's the solution I like, one tick and it works fine. Do you have any idea how to fix filewatcher issue ? Should I change my whole question?

Comment: I don't see why you would need file watcher. And by the way don't use webpack alongside `create-react-app`, it already uses webpack internally and installing it on top can cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Solution one (hinted by Michael Jungo): 
 Disable `safe-write` in Webstorm options > Appearance&Behavior>System Settings> untick "safe-write"

Solution two (for babel filewatcher):

1. Run `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`
2. Add `--plugins transform-class-properties` to file watcher arguments.

Both result in easier refreshing changes on react app site. First one manual second automatic. I'm novice and maybe don't understand what exactly is happening but it makes developing easier if I don't have to always restart server.